# How can i pass the inputtext value to the next VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="oneTestHomepageclass" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="true">

<apex:messages />

<apex:form >

<p><b>Welcome to the site</b></p><br />

<apex:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:1em;">

<p><b>UserName</b><br />

<apex:inputText required="true" id="username" value="{!usernameinput}"/>

</p>

<p><b>Password</b><br />

<apex:inputSecret id="password" value="{!passwordinput}"/>

</p>

 <apex:commandButton action="{!login}" value="login" id="login"/>

<p>{!Warningmessage}</p><br /> 
</apex:panelGrid>

</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

I want to pass the username value to other VF pages.
should I just use pg.getParameters().put('', ); statement
or can I make use of inputtext ID to use in other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the parameters using the [PageReference class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm).
Following should be the login method:

```
public PageReference login(){
    // do the processing
    PageReference nextPage = Page.PageName;
    nextPage.getParameters().put('passwordinput', passwordinput);
    nextPage.getParameters().put('usernameinput', usernameinput);
    pageReference.setRedirect(true); 
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of id in the inputtext tag?I thought it can be used to get the input text to other VF pages as well?is it not?

Comment: You can get the value of the inputText from the 'id', but then you need to use javascript for getting the value.

Comment: Oh, now i get it why in all other examples javascript is used,Cool thanks.umm so i am left with this method only right?

Comment: Yes, just create the method with the appropriate logic. Do mark it resolved and useful if it is working.